# How does react conditionally give the minified production bundle when NODE_ENV=production?

Tags: reactjs, build, npm

If you build your project with `NODE_ENV=production`, react automatically includes the minified production verison of the lib in the bundle. Conversely, a non production build will include the dev unminified version of react.

How is this being achieved?

If we install react:

```
npm install --save react
```

Then look at its `package.json` for the `main` key, it points to:

```
"main": "react.js",
```

Looking at `react.js` the contents of the file are simply:

```
module.exports = require('./lib/React');
```

Looking in `./lib/React` I was expecting to see a conditional that loaded the minified build or not, but the conditionals seem to do other stuff:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  var ReactElementValidator = require('./ReactElementValidator');
  createElement = ReactElementValidator.createElement;
  createFactory = ReactElementValidator.createFactory;
  cloneElement = ReactElementValidator.cloneElement;
}

var __spread = _assign;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  var warned = false;
  __spread = function () {
    process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? warning(warned, 'React.__spread is deprecated and should not be used. Use ' + 'Object.assign directly or another helper function with similar ' + 'semantics. You may be seeing this warning due to your compiler. ' + 'See fb.me/react-spread-deprecation for more details.') : void 0;
    warned = true;
    return _assign.apply(null, arguments);
  };
}
```

What is react doing exactly between prod and dev builds? It doesn't seem like it interacts with the minified and unminified builds in `/dist` as I thought.